# How to reach a child object getter function from a father object vector

Tags: c++, oop, vector

I have an assignment to make, where I have a vector of 'Robots' - an object I have. I have another Object, named QuickLimitedRobot, which inherits from Robot but have one more field to it - limit, which is an integer.

I have a vector that contains all of the robots, whether they are limited or other inherited types of the Robot Object, and I need to get to the getLimit() function on my code, in a vector node that I already know that is a QuickLimitedRobot.

```
void RobotDB::moveLimitedRobot(const int rNum, const std::string &rDirection){
int cellValue;
int locX=robots[rNum]->getCoordinate().getX();
int locY=robots[rNum]->getCoordinate().getY();
//@todo: :(
QuickLimitedRobot tempQuick=*robots[rNum];
int rLim=tempQuick.getLimit();
```

My compiler won't compile this because I tried to convert Robot to 'non-scalar type' QuickLimitedRobot.

Someone can please lead me to a solution?

thx in advance!

Comment: Could you please provide a [MCVE] that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Downcasting has to be explicit, use `dynamic_cast` or `static_cast`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `dynamic_cast` for this.  This looks like:

```
QuickLimitedRobot* tempQuick = dynamic_cast<QuickLimitedRobot*>(robots[rNum]);
if (tempQuick) {
    int rLim = tempQuick->getLimit();
```

Or since you say you already know it's a `QuickLimitedRobot`, you can cast by reference.  If you get this wrong, it will throw an exception.

```
QuickLimitedRobot& tempQuick = dynamic_cast<QuickLimitedRobot&>(*robots[rNum]);
int rLim = tempQuick.getLimit();
```

Or, if you're really 100% absolutely certain it's a `QuickLimitedRobot`, and the inheritance is not virtual, you can even try `static_cast`.  This time if you get it wrong, using the resulting reference is undefined behavior - a crash if you're lucky.

```
QuickLimitedRobot& tempQuick = static_cast<QuickLimitedRobot&>(*robots[rNum]);
int rLim = tempQuick.getLimit();
```